# Application "freeze" while opening a new Stage window

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Say, I have a `MenuBar` with few `MenuItem`'s in it. Each `MenuItem` is responsible for opening a different `Stage` window. How can I avoid the "freeze" of the application after clicking one of the above mentioned `MenuItem`'s, when the app is diggesting the code of the new `Stage`?

Comment: Can you post an example, I've been unable to reproduce your issue from the description above

Comment: It is a good idea to not put everything into your UI Thread. That's probably the reason why it looks like it 'freezes', because your UI Thread waits until the Stage is loaded.

Comment: @MuratK. yes exactly, it looks like it waits until the Stage is fully loaded. But is there a way, to allow the user to work with the app even when the new Stage is not fully loaded? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The android developer guides are really good. You can use a Handler for this kind of issue. [See here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html)

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following:

```
new Thread( new Task<Pane>()
{
   protected Pane call()
   {
      Pane  gui = .... ;
      // this part runs on a background thread
      // build or load your GUI here.
      return  gui;
   }

   protected void succeeded()
   {
      // this part will run on fx thread
      // add your GUI to the scene here
      Pane  gui = getValue();
   }

}).start();
```